# Maintaining focus after hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to show a div on focusing a link. But how to make sure the div does not disappear when I remove the hover from the link. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g6jMF/2/)  is the link to the code

Basically, I just want to show the div on hover, but close it using the close button. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try the on mouseenter event described here

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

ie

```
$("#clickme").mouseenter(function() { 
    e.preventDefault();  
    $("#draggable").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the probleme is causing bye .slideToggle('slow') and the hover event

you can use mouseenter() 
or just :

```
$("#clickme").hover(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#draggable").show('slow'); // or anay other effect like slideDown()
 });
```